# Aggregate function to create frequency matrix in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I am a noob here so please don't judge me ;)

I want to create a frequency matrix where the column names are authors and the rownames are languages with frequency counts.

My data looks like this:

```
language    author
----------------------
ita         Goethe
ger         Schiller
eng         Marx
fr          Marx
po          Schiller
eng         Marx
```

As a result I would like to have something like this

```
            ita    ger     eng     fr    po
----------------------------------------------
Schiller     0      1       0       0    1
Goethe       1      0       0       0    0
Marx         0      0       2       1    0
```

I tried to use the aggregate() function with something like the following:

```
df1 <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
aggregate(. ~ language, df1, sum)
```

But it does not seem to work.
How can I rewrite it to get the second table.

Thank you so much in advance! Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Phil's data,

```
library(tidyr)
table(dat) %>% data.frame() %>% spread(language, Freq)

#     author eng fr ger ita po
#1   Goethe   0  0   0   1  0
#2     Marx   2  1   0   0  0
#3 Schiller   0  0   1   0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I recognize that you may be looking for a base version to determine this, but offhand the tidyverse way is:

```
library(tidyverse)

# creating data
dat <- tribble(~language,    ~author,
        "ita",         "Goethe",
        "ger",         "Schiller",
        "eng",         "Marx",
        "fr",         "Marx",
        "po",         "Schiller",
        "eng",         "Marx")

dat %>% 
  count(language, author) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = language, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  author     eng    fr   ger   ita    po
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Marx         2     1     0     0     0
2 Schiller     0     0     1     0     1
3 Goethe       0     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
language    author
ita         Goethe
ger         Schiller
eng         Marx
fr          Marx
po          Schiller
eng         Marx", h = T)

as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$author, df$language))

         eng fr ger ita po
Goethe     0  0   0   1  0
Marx       2  1   0   0  0
Schiller   0  0   1   0  1
```

This sorts the rownames and colnames in alpabethical order though.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `acast`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df, author ~ language, length)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(language = c("ita", "ger", "eng", "fr", "po", 
"eng"), author = c("Goethe", "Schiller", "Marx", "Marx", "Schiller", 
"Marx")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```